# Vector with different types defined at compile time

Tags: c++, variables, boost, vector, compile-time

My question is rather short:

I need a vector which holds different types like:

```
std::vector<int,double> vec;
vec.emplace_back((int) 1);
vec.emplace_back((double) 2.0);
```

I tried using boost:variant, but the problem is that one has to visit/get the numbers out of the vector each time one wants to use the values.

I define initial values for the vector so the types are static and are defined at compile time. Moreover, I want to be able to iterate over them (that is why i use a vector- it could also be a map or any other container).

What I want is to use the vector entries like a int or double in the program without using boost::get or something of that kind. I think this should be possible because the type of each entry is totally defined at compile time but I do not know how to get it to work.

```
double d=vec[1]*3.0; //this should somehow work
int i=vec[0]*8;      //this also without any get or anything
```

I tried using tuples, but I do not have much experience with them and it seems rather hard to iterate over them.

```
for(auto &elem : vec) std::cout << elem << std:endl; //this or sth. similar should also work
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible without something like `boost::variant` or some variation of it.

Comment: @AnT You mean some *variant* of it? har har

Comment: EIther as @Ant said, or you'd have to have a common base class and store pointers or smart pointers. But even then, you'd have to `dynamic_cast()`, etc if the classes have nothing in common. If you require overloading `operator<<` and `operator*`, the required operations would both *somehow work*

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that this vector is not a good tool for the underlying problem in the first place (Just a guess of course, as I do not know the underlying problem). You probably either should have two vectors or get the actual datatype straight.

Comment: In your example you can just use a vector of doubles.

Comment: @TuttiFruttiJacuzzi: Then make one of the types a std::string - if you want.

Comment: Are your `ints` and `doubles` always going to be stored together as pairs?

Comment: No, there can also be more types like int, double, std::string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a tuple indeed. CPP is a strong typed language. Deal with it.

Now, if you want to iterate, consider using Boost Fusion:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc3701ba8bb6246)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    tuple<int, double, std::string> demo(42, 3.1415, "hello pie universe");

    fusion::for_each(demo, std::cout << arg1 << "\n");

    auto& v2 = get<1>(demo);
    v2 *= 10;
    std::cout << "\nNew v2: "         << v2   << "\n";
    std::cout << "Tuple after edit: " << demo << "\n";
}
```

Which prints

```
42
3.1415
hello pie universe

New v2: 31.415
Tuple after edit: (42 31.415 hello pie universe)
```

Comment: Can you explain how I would get for example the second value to make a calculation with it? And can i change the values without changing the type and does it still work?

Comment: If I'm to take your comment literal, then yes, and: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc3701ba8bb6246)

Comment: Perhaps mention that this can be achieved with C++11 without invoking boost?

Comment: @Gerard I'm not aware of the equivalent for fusion::for_each in c++11 (yes, the phoenix expression can be replaced by polymorphic lambda (c++14) or a polymorphic function object; the tuple can be `std::tuple` just as well. I also don't think `std::tuple` implement io streaming operators)